# Laravel not applying coupon using Billing/Cashier

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am trying to apply a coupon to a user’s subscription upon creation.

To do this I am using the following code:

```
$user = Auth::user();
if(!empty($request->coupon)){
    $user->subscription('monthly')->withCoupon($request->coupon)->create($request->stripeToken);
} else {
    $user->subscription('monthly')->create($request->stripeToken);
}
```

I have checked the value of `$request->coupon` and it contains my coupon. The coupon exists and is in Stripe (this is validated programatically so I know the coupon is OK).

The subscription is created within Stripe, but billed at the full amount, not taking into account the coupon.

The coupon is in the test environment, as is the website—the transaction comes through in the test environment too.

Comment: Are you completely sure that your code goes in the correct condition `!empty()`? or you can try applying your coupon this way to just test where the problem comes from: `$user->subscription('monthly')->withCoupon('`**with-your-code**` ')->create($request->stripeToken);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking if an object property is set using the `empty` function will not have the desired effect, because the class would need to have the [`__isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset) magic method defined for `empty` to work on inaccesible properties.

That aside, the `Http\Illuminate\Request` class uses `__get` to access input parameters, which means that `__isset` wouldn't even work in this case, because the `coupon` property is not really defined within the class. So your condition almost surely goes to the `else` block with your current code (even though you have the `coupon` input parameter present).

That's why the method [`has`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests#retrieving-input) exists, to determine if the request contains a non-empty value for an input item. So use this instead:

```php
if ($request->has('coupon'))
```

Comment: Cracking answer, thanks.  I should have manually checked the if-statement (which I did do shortly after this was posted), but the logical thing to assume that if a string isn't empty `empty` would return false.  Live and learn :)